# Error with expand-file-name function in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using Emacs 25.2.1 under Arch Linux.

When I try to expand `/..` or `/../` or `/../rest/of/path` paths with `expand-file-name`, there is not changes. Is it a bug? Could I use other (better) function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior: `/../` is the ["super-root"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory#Super-root) on certain file systems:

> Some Unix systems support a directory below the root directory. Normally, "/.." points back to the same inode as "/", however, under MUNIX, this can be changed to point to a super-root directory, where remote trees can be mounted. If, for example, two workstations "pcs2a" and "pcs2b" were connected via "connectnodes" and "uunite" startup script, "/../pcs2b" could be used to access the root directory of "pcs2b" from "pcs2a".

Comment: I had any idea about this. Thanks!